# Поделитесь хорошими гайдами по созданию сайтов на Node

Tags: node.js

Я занимался фронт-эндом и в бэк не лез, теперь когда решил изучить нод понял, что не могу найти ни одного толкового урока, где скажут как написать, к примеру, свой блог и прикрепить к нему верстку, есть только куча уроков как делать авторизацию со стороны нода и т.п. Так же есть уроки которые снимались пару лет назад и зная как js развивается, не хотелось бы учить по ним, буду благодарен за толковые статьи и видео уроки.

Comment: Но если уж ваше решение окончательное, то у O'Reilly есть книга переведенная на русский язык Шелли Пауэрс - "Изучаем Node.js" и документация на  http://nodejs.org/. Ну и на английском [EnSO есть такая страничка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js/5511507)

Comment: @AlexKrass а можно где-нибудь почитать, почему бэк на ноде - к плохому? Или почему Вы так решили?

Comment: @AlexKrass почему выкинуть. А что значит нормальный язык? Просто node не совсем подходит для сайтов...

Comment: https://expressjs.com/

Comment: @Alexxosipov да не плох он. На express'е вполне себе нормально сайты поживают. Правда, я лично больше для API использую, но и полноценные сайты тоже на нём можно делать легко.

Comment: @Alexxosipov я не говорил что бек на ноде к плохому, но начинать свое знакомство с беком на ноде как по мне не самая лучшая идея. Тут больше проблем с тем, что он молодой и найти хорошее описание "как создать правильную серверную архитектуру и не иметь проблем в будущем с ней" с примерами на NodeJS сложнее. Как там было про выстрелить себе в ногу: "node.JS: Вы начинаете асинхронно стрелять из асинхронных рук в асинхронные ноги, асинхронно не попадаете и запутываетесь в этой каше." Лучше изучать премудрости бека имея примеры и базу, которые можно легко найти и разобрать.

Comment: @C.Raf.T, можно поподробней, почему nodejs не подходит для сайтов? я сколько чего читал смотрел, везде говориться, что на данный момент это лучшее решение

Comment: @Air я не сказал, что не подходит. просто он сложнее и дороже. если нужно набросать маленький сайт-проект, то есть более простые и дешевые варианты...

Answer (score 4):

....Пишу в ответ, т.к. не хватает репутации для комментирования....
У меня была подобная ситуация с Nodejs: когда смотришь курс, читаешь книги, и кажется, что стоишь на месте - дальше "Hello world" дело не идет.
Но потом, когда количество переросло в качество - я понял, что для создания сервера у меня уже есть все необходимые знания. Их нужно было только собрать в кучу.

Принцип прост:

1) Браузер делает запрос (просит html, css, js, картинку);

2) Этот запрос надо обработать (понять что хочет браузер);

3) Дать ему ответ.

И это все. Авторизация, работа с БД - это уровень чуть выше. Я сейчас только двигаюсь к нему).
Вот пример кода сервера, который подойдет для статического сайта:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path");

// создаем объект для удобной работы с MIME-type файлов
var mimeType = {
    ".js": "text/javascript",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
    ".bmp": "image/bmp",
    ".png": "image/png",
    ".json": "application/json",
    ".ico": "image/x-icon",
    ".html":"text/html"
};

var port = 3000;
var server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Сервер работает по адресу localhost:"+port);
})

//каждый запрос сервера генерирует событие "request", обрабатываем его и даем ответ. Все в одном
server.on("request", function(req, res){
    //в запросе содержится URL, который мы разбиваем на части
    var urlParse = url.parse(req.url);
    //при первом запросе на localhost путь будет пустой
    if (urlParse.pathname == "/") {
        urlParse.pathname = "/index.html";
    };
    // для установления правильного MIME-type определяем расширение файла
    var extname = path.extname(urlParse.pathname);
    //формируем правильный путь к файлу для чтения (path.join), читаем файл и отправляем его браузеру.
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, urlParse.pathname), function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mimeType[extname]});
            res.end(data);
    });
});
```

https://coursehunters.net/course/itvdn-nodejs  - вот крутой видеокурс по Nodejs

Comment: держи плюс, что бы мог и комменты писать...)))

Comment: теперь не отмажусь)

Comment: это точно)))))))

Comment: Помню этот ответ, но не нашел его...  Благодарю...