# Стили и js файлы виднелись в koa?

Tags: node.js, koa.js

Использую модуль koa-static-server, но мне непонятно как вывести все стили и js файлы?
Мой код

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
Router = require('koa-router'),
logger = require('koa-logger'),
views = require('koa-views'),
serve = require('koa-static-server'),
app = new Koa(),
router = new Router();

app.use(logger());
app.use(serve({rootDir: __dirname + 'public', rootPath: '/public'}));
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {extension: 'pug'}));

routers('/', 'login', {title: 'Авторизация'});
routers('/registration', 'registration', {title: 'Регистрация'});

function routers(path, page, object) {
    router.get(path, async (ctx) => {
       await ctx.render(page, object);
    })
}

app.use(router.routes());
module.exports = app;
```

В layout.pug

```
Doctype html
html
  head
    title=title
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles/style.css')
    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="/javascript/modal.js")
    script(src="/javascript/form.js")
....
```

Но в ответ получаю в консоле

> GET localhost:3000/styles/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED
>   GET localhost:3000/javascript/modal.js net::ERR_ABORTED
>   GET localhost:3000/javascript/form.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Пути у меня такой

[image: Пути у меня такой]

Comment: c `koa.js`дел не имел,  но по аналогии с нативной  Нодой:  `__dirname + "public"`   будет что-то типа `C:User\Name\Projectpublic`. По идее нужно написать `__dirname + "\public"`

Comment: @Дмытрык Нет не помогло

Comment: Кстати, в следующей строчке, у Вас, как раз, так и написано `__dirname + '/views'`

Comment: @Дмытрык Но это я подключал рендер для страниц. Просто статику не понятно как испольовать в этом фреймворке

Comment: и еще, что такое `rootPath`? Нужно ли, вообще, к `__dirname` присоединять `public`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-static-server Вот адрес на модуль. rootPath {string} optional rewrite path

Comment: Без rootPath будет выходит на экране ENOENT: нет такого файла или каталога, стат 'C:\OpenServer\domains\crm_nodejs1\public\index.html'

Comment: Нужно ли, вообще, к `__dirname` присоединять `public`. `__dirname`, как раз и будет `rootDir`, по логике вещей.  В описании к модулю написано, что `rootDir` - это директория с которой стартует сервер - все.

Comment: @Дмытрык Не совсем понял, то есть __dirname уибрать? Если убрать, то все равно выходит ошибка с подключением

Comment: Нет же, `public`, после `__dirname`  убирать.

Comment: @Дмытрык Так еще раз, чтобы я догнал, я должен написать вот так? app.use(serve({rootDir: __dirname, rootPath: '/public'}));

Comment: Да, уже написали бы давно). П.С.: это пока только предположение, что проблема здесь.

Comment: @Дмытрык Нет, все равно одно и тоже

Comment: еще есть вариант, что `__dirname` как-то не так системой определяется из-за фреймворка. Или вообще, не определяется. Выведите его в консоль.  Пробуйте ручками путь к папке с сервером указать.

Comment: Выводит C:\OpenServer\domains\crm_nodejs1

Comment: Ну? Это путь к папке где расположен Ваш файл сервера?

Comment: @Дмытрык это корневой путь, И когда выводишь вот так console.log(app.use(serve({rootDir: __dirname + 'public', rootPath: '/public'})));
 то получаю { subdomainOffset: 2, proxy: false, env: 'development' }
Может что-то тут моэно понять

Comment: @Дмытрык Я короче плюнул на модуль, посмотрел на другие модули и уввидел другой модул, попроще koa-static и все норм

Comment: Ясно) Я, пока, вообще, фреймворки не использую. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740524/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-node/740849#740849 В ответе я написал код простого сервера для статического сайта. Пользуйтесь, если надо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменял модуль на [koa-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-static)

И сделал так

```
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'));
```

И все нормально