# Как указать серверу NODEJS, что бы он читал не только html, но и css и js?

Tags: node.js

> Хочу сразу отметить, что знаю у существовании модуля experss и он меня не интересует

Есть простой сервер:

```
const http = require('http'),
      fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer()

server.on('request', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' });
    fs.readFile('./frontend/index.html', (err, content) => {
        res.write(content);

        res.end();

    })
});

server.listen(8888);
```

Вот `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test NodeJS && Webpack</title>
    <base href="./" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Site</h1>
    </header>
    <main>Main</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Этот сервер читает только html...

Как мне заставить читать `CSS` И `JS` файлы???

И еще вопрос такой. Правильно ли использовать тут модуль `fs`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы это сделать, в параметры метода чтения нужно передавать динамический путь, который будет зависеть от запроса сервера. Так же, при ответе на каждый такой запрос, нужно указывать динамический `content-type`, который будет соответствовать запрашиваему файлу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740524/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-node/740849#740849   Обязательно посмотри ссылку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то у себя использовал такой вариант, думаю будет полезно.

```
 ...
 fs.readFile('./' + request.url, function(err, data) {
     if (!err) {
         var dotoffset = request.url.lastIndexOf('.');
         var mimetype = dotoffset == -1
              ? 'text/plain'
              : {
                 '.html' : 'text/html',
                 '.ico'  : 'image/x-icon',
                 '.jpg'  : 'image/jpeg',
                 '.png'  : 'image/png',
                 '.gif'  : 'image/gif',
                 '.css'  : 'text/css',
                 '.js'   : 'text/javascript',
                 '.map'  : 'text/javascript'
                  }[ request.url.substr(dotoffset) ];
                    response.setHeader('Content-type' , mimetype);
                    response.end(data);
                } else {
                    console.log ('file not found: ' + request.url);
                    response.writeHead(404, "Not Found");
                    response.end();
                }
    });
```

Comment: Благодарю, я понял смысл...