# Nodejs не создает папку node_modules и не работает script который работал

Tags: node.js

Коллеги. решил углубится в `nodejs`. Был вопрос [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943567/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-nodejs-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-html-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-css-%D0%B8-js) на который я получил ответ, который очень мне помог. Все прекрасно работало.

После перерыва на денек,  пример выше по ссылке перестал работать.  Я подумал, что грешным делом чего-то напортачил... Была куча переделок примеров. Не разобравшись решил с нуля все сделать.

Далее последовательность моих действий.

1. Создаю репозиторий на `github`.
2. Клонирую его.
3. Далее команда `npm init` ( ***Естественно в папке с проектом*** )
4. Далее `npm install` и тут первая проблема, не создается папка `node_modules`.
5. Далее создаю некоторые папки и файлы ( ***см. скин ниже*** )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам `Server`

Вот этот пример работает

```
const http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer().on('request', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
   res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' });
    fs.readFile('./frontend/index.html', (err, content) => {
        res.end(content);
    });
}).listen(3333);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот этот пример уже не работает, хотя прекрасно работал

```
    http.createServer().on('request', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    fs.readFile('./frontend' + req.url, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            var dotoffset = req.url.lastIndexOf('.');
            var mimetype = dotoffset == -1 ?
                'text/plain' :
                {
                    '.html': 'text/html',
                    '.ico': 'image/x-icon',
                    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
                    '.png': 'image/png',
                    '.gif': 'image/gif',
                    '.css': 'text/css',
                    '.js': 'text/javascript',
                    '.map': 'text/javascript'
                } [req.url.substr(dotoffset)];
            res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
            res.end(data);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('file not found: ' + req.url);
            res.writeHead(404, "Not Found");
            res.end();
        }
    });
}).listen(3333);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже более суток борюсь. Что не так?

> На счет того, что нет папки `node_modules` подозреваю, что
>   установилась глобально, но не подозреваю из-за чего и почему...

Если кому интересно можно клонировать по [ссылке](https://github.com/sarnor/test.git)

Comment: после клонирования репозитори, команда `npm init` лишняя. Эта команда подразумевает создание нового проекта. По идее, она должна перезатереть ваш `packege.json`, ну и видимо удаляет папку `node_modules`

Comment: @Дмытрык, когда создаю репу, у меня нет файла `packege.json` и я командой  `npm init` ее создаю

Comment: Тогда команда `npm install` лишняя, т.к. она подразумевает инсталяцию зависимостей указанных в файле `packege.json`. А вот команда `npm install ws` - установит в Ваш проект модуль `ws`  запишет его в зависимости и создаст папку `node_modules`. П.С. глобально папка `node_modules` создастся, только если поставить флаг `-g` при установке какого-либо пакета

Comment: @Дмытрык, это я знаю... Меня смущает другое, раньше когда я запускал команду `npm install` папка `node_modules` создавалась. Хотя меня щас больше беспокоит тот факт, что не работает `server`

Comment: На счет сервера - посмотрите мой ответ, на который я Вам ссылку давал. Там есть ответ. ... Введите в урл строку `localhost:3333/index.html` - заработает

Comment: Забыл про ошибку, ща закину скрин

Comment: Кстати, я бы не советовал в разработке использовать `nodemon`, т.к. он будет поддерживать работу сервера, даже тогда, когда Вы закроете терминал или среду разработки...зачем лишння нагрузка на систему. Лучше использовать `supervisor`. Но это лично мои предпочтения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89764/discussion-between-air-and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path");

// создаем объект для удобной работы с MIME-type файлов
var mimeType = {
    ".js": "text/javascript",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
    ".bmp": "image/bmp",
    ".png": "image/png",
    ".json": "application/json",
    ".ico": "image/x-icon",
    ".html":"text/html"
};

var port = 3000;
var server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Сервер работает по адресу localhost:"+port);
})

//каждый запрос сервера генерирует событие "request", обрабатываем его и даем ответ. Все в одном
server.on("request", function(req, res){
    //в запросе содержится URL, который мы разбиваем на части
    var urlParse = url.parse(req.url);
    //при первом запросе на localhost путь будет пустой
    if (urlParse.pathname === "/") {
        urlParse.pathname = "/index.html";
    };
    // для установления правильного MIME-type определяем расширение файла
    var extname = path.extname(urlParse.pathname);
    //формируем правильный путь к файлу для чтения (path.join), читаем файл и отправляем его браузеру.
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, urlParse.pathname), function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mimeType[extname]});
            res.end(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Благодарю, дальше думаю разберусь... Я понял суть ошибки...